# JPG Image extension not inserting into Custom table of wp

Tags: database, wordpress

I've created a custom table on database and I need to upload image from my template page **member**. In this page I've done all the codings. I'm able to insert data but stuck on the image insert. I can get the file name but unable to get the extension.

Here is my inserting code of my template file.

```
 $tmpfile = explode(".", $_FILES['image']['name']);
 $newfile = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($tmpfile);
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], ABSPATH . '/wp-content/themes/themename/inc/images/' . $newfile);

 $sql = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO members(member_image) VALUES (%s)", $newfile));
```

The above code shows the field value without extension as: https://screenshots.firefox.com/w7aDRfXESHZEw39s/localhost

Here is my html form field:

```
     <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
     </form>
```

All other text fields are inserted but only image can't be derived with extension. I can't figure out the problem. I've also tried by adding .jpg extension but it didn't work.